# How to split a column into multiple integers of fixed size?

Tags: r, split, integer

I have an integer as a column that I would like to split into multiple, seperate integers

Creating a list of dataframes using `split()` doesn't work for my later purposes

```
df <- as.data.frame(runif(n = 10000, min = 1, max = 10))
```

where `split()` creates a list of dataframe which I can't use for further purposes, where I need a separate integer as `"Values"`

```
map.split <- split(df, (as.numeric(rownames(df)) - 1) %/% 250) # this is not the trick
```

My goal is to split the column into different integer (not saved under the Global Environment "Data", but "Values")

This would be the slow way:

```
VecList1 <- df[1:250,]
VecList2 <- df[251:500,]
```

with

```
str(VecList1)
Int [1:250] 1 1 10 5 3 ....
```

Any advice welcome

Comment: Can you give an example of what your desired output would be?

Comment: A set of integers as shown in the lower part of my question, each 250 values

Comment: Your output (integers) is inconsistent with your sample input (floats, made with `runif`). Really, please make this question *reproducible* with **small** consistent sample data and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Your use of columns and integers is confusing. You want a series of vectors?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting correctly (not clear to me), here's a reduced problem and what I think you're asking for.

```r
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(10, min = 1, max = 10))
df$Values <- (seq_len(nrow(df))-1) %/% 4
df
#           x Values
# 1  2.663940      0
# 2  7.321366      0
# 3  6.159937      0
# 4  2.512467      0
# 5  9.494554      1
# 6  9.491275      1
# 7  2.162431      1
# 8  8.501039      1
# 9  5.212167      2
# 10 5.949854      2
```

If all you need is that `Values` column as its own object, then you can just change `df$Values <- ...` to `Values <- ...`.

Comment: If you might know a way to easy subset the $Values column in your example into different, separate by value, integers; then this would work for me as well

Comment: `split(df$x, (seq_len(nrow(df))-1) %/% 4)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing this (although it's probably better to figure out a way where you don't need a series of separate vectors, but rather work with columns in a single matrix):

```
df <- data.frame(a=runif(n = 10000, min = 1, max = 10))
mx<-matrix(df$a,nrow=250)
for (i in 1:NCOL(mx)) {
  assign(paste0("VecList",i),mx[,i])}
```

Note: using `assign` is generally not advisable. Whatever it is you're trying to achieve, there's probably a better way of doing it without creating a series of new vectors in the global environment.